# How can I change the GPG key used in kwallet?

Tags: debian, gpg, kwallet

I'm using kwallet on my Debian system with a GPG key. The key I used while setting up the system has now expired. I've already created a new one, which works as expected for mailing etc., but I don't know how to use this to encrypt kwallet.

Comment: what do i have to do in kleopatra?

Comment: I see my new OpenPGP key in kleopatra, wich is valid till 2018. When i start

Comment: I see my new OpenPGP key in kleopatra, wich is valid till 2018. When i start the kwalletmanager and press here the "change password" button, i get an error, which tells me the key signature which is actually used. This is the signature of the old key. How can i tell kwallet to use the new one?

Comment: @GAD3R: I don't want to extend the lifetime of my old key, i want to use the new one.

Comment: Hello. Have you tried to open wallet manager. Export the wallet, delete it and import it?

Comment: As far as I remember: yes. But i will (re)try this the next time I'm sitting in front of this computer.

Comment: @BenjB this should be answer for this question

Comment: I will add it, thanks! @QkiZ

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following:

1. Open wallet manager
2. Export the wallet
3. Delete the wallet in KDEWallet
4. Reimport the deleted wallet again

That should fix the issue.

Comment: it's important to name a new wallet with `kdewallet` because system expects that name in settings.

Comment: Thanks, but meanwhile I have a new system and not using KDEWallet any more

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong but I wasn't able to just re-import the wallet after deleting (got some error saying its unable to open the file).  What did work, though, was to first create a new one and _then_ import the passwords into that new wallet.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

All steps but #2 are done in KDE `Wallet Manager`

1. Do `File` > `Export as XML`. `Export as encrypted` as backup too.
2. (optional) If you do not have have a new key already (mine was expired) - create one. I did so in `kleopatra`. Created one with default choices - personal OpenPGP key pair with RSA, with passphrase.
3. Do `File` > `Delete Wallet`
4. Create new wallet with name `kdewallet` (`File` > `New Wallet`) using GPG encryption and referencing the needed key created at step #2
5. Do `File` > `Import XML` to import old wallet content.
6. (optional) Everything should be good now. If anything went wrong, you can delete new wallet and `Import encrypted` the old backup with old content and old key.